# php7.0.2 Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault

Tags: php-7

I am running php-7.0.2 with codeigniter (a php mvc frame). I got some segmentation faults which caused core dumps. And, I found that these segmentation faults  randomly occurred when the child php-fpm  processes shutdown and restart. I don't know why.

Using gdb "bt" to display the core dump:

```
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www                                                               '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.  
\#0  zend_string_release (ht=0x114dae0) at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_string.h:269  
269     /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_string.h: No such file or directory.  
        in /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_string.h  
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install php7-7.0.2-20160407105024.x86_64  
(gdb) bt  
\#0  zend_string_release (ht=0x114dae0) at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_string.h:269  
\#1  zend_hash_destroy (ht=0x114dae0) at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_hash.c:1273  
\#2  0x000000000080647b in module_destructor (module=0x14b6ae0)  
    at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_API.c:2509  
\#3  0x000000000080075c in module_destructor_zval (zv=<value optimized out>)  
    at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend.c:615  
\#4  0x000000000080dcff in _zend_hash_del_el_ex (ht=0x1154780)  
    at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_hash.c:1013  
\#5  _zend_hash_del_el (ht=0x1154780) at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_hash.c:1037  
\#6  zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy (ht=0x1154780) at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend_hash.c:1489  
\#7  0x0000000000800096 in zend_shutdown () at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/Zend/zend.c:840  
\#8  0x00000000007a2a6a in php_module_shutdown () at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/main/main.c:2339  
\#9  0x000000000089e45d in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>)  
    at /home/smt/phpng/php-7.0.2/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1997  
(gdb) quit
```

The php-fpm.log is as following:

```
[20-Apr-2016 08:00:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 11751 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 3600.462022 seconds from start
```

I am very curious about this bug.

Until now, I am sure that the core dumps occurred when the fpm restarted. The restarts were caused by the command 'kill -10 fpm-master-process-ids'. Or, the fpm also restarted when it had processed 'pm.max_requests' requests.

However, the core dumps didn't occur at every restart and the probability of core dumps was very small. I cannot find the role.

Fortunately, I have installed the 7.0.5 version to replace the 7.0.2 version in our production environment and it had run for three days without core dumps.

I cannot find any modification in the changelogs from 7.0.2 to 7.0.5. This is exactly a very strange bug and I want to know the reason. who can tell me something about this bug?

Comment: This was a bug, will be fixed in 7.0.6

Comment: Yes, I have found this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71662&edit=3

it said this bug was fixed in 7.0.4, but we cannot find in changlog

Comment: What causes this error? I cannot find the modification for this bug in 7.0.6 branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to 7.0.5, core dump has not occurred for 2 weeks. So, this bug has been fixed in 7.0.5!

I still don't know what case this bug.

I am a curious cat. @_@